# Is there an advantage to using .data over a for loop?

Tags: d3.js

Like the title says, I'm just curious if there is an advantage over using .data to iterate to draw nodes on the screen over using a for loop in d3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using D3's data model gives you lots of advantages. In addition to allowing you to create the elements, it also binds the data you give to those elements. This enables you to pass in new data later and match to what's already there. The selections D3 provides allow you to easily add new elements, modify existing and remove ones that are no longer represented in the data.

The [three little circles tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html) illustrates these concepts and should give you a better idea of the advantages of using D3's data model.